# Android Setando Nome com colchetes no parametro body json

Tags: android, annotation

Estou tendo o seguinte problema: Estou usando a biblioteca Android Rest API 
https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API, e estou tentando um post, mas o post só aceita um único parametro, que estou tentando enviar como um objeto, sendo o Json espera receber o seguinte :

```
public class User(){

  int USER_ID[Id]
  String USER_nome[nome]
}
```

Sendo que eu não posso colocar colchetes como nome desse atributo no meu object, então como eu faço para mandar esse objeto?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO. Você pode postar o JSON que é gerado? Também seria interessante que você postasse um pouco mais do seu código para que possam te ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Túlio F. :

Esse são alguns dos parametros do Body que o servidor está esperando :

mobile_session[token],
mobile_session[email]

Essa é uma classe que eu criei agora pra exemplificar como estou fazendo

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://demo2601066.mockable.io/", converters = {MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class,FormHttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface TKSAL {
    @Post(value = "testeJonathan")
    Resposta criarmetodo(Envio envio);
}
```

Esse é o meu Objeto Envio :

```
@JsonIdentityReference
public class Envio {
    @JsonProperty("mobile_session[token]")
    Long token;

    @JsonProperty("mobile_session[email]")
    String email;
}
```

Repare que eu não posso colocar como nome de variavel mobile_session[token] porque a notação não aceita colchetes como nome de variavel, então como eu faço isso ?